# How to create a dropdown with two searchboxes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox, selectize.js

I want to create a dropdown with two different searchboxes parallel to each other. 
like shown in the images. [[Live example]](https://www.justproperty.com/en/). I have tried searching and did some code with bootstrap but couldn't achieve it.

[image] [image]

Is there any library or ui tools kit that provides such dropdown?  or any other example?

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<div class="container row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." id="text1">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span>

                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

                    </li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span>

                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

                    </li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div >
                <button id="mybtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>Search</button>
  </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-default {
    border:0;
}
.input-group {
    border:1px solid darkgrey;
}
#text1 {
    border:none;
}
.container {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
}
#mybtn{
    background-color:skyblue;
}
```

Fiddle:[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/b1nwwtvo/5/)

Comment: i am trying to put two search boxes into one dropdown, that will search from list. will you please check the link I provided?